# highlighting text and providing defintions in .net

Tags: asp.net, regex, performance, replace

We have a large document of text (stored in a MSSQL database) and we need to provide dictionary like lookups for words when they are hovered over.

For instance if there was the following sentence:
"The quick dog jumped over the brown fox" our users could create a "definition" for any of those words such as "quick", "dog", "jumped over" etc and we need to highlight such text and when they mouseover provide the text that has been set in the definition.

Currently we have an implementation that does the job however it suffers from incredible bad performance, the current implementation uses Regex to parse the text and insert a snippet of Javascript right after the word in the text if it matches a definition. Now seeings as we can have anywhere up to 400 or more definitions and the text can be several paragraphs long or more this hangs the entire server and makes the app non-repsonsive.

I have tried to optimise the code by fiddling with compiled regex but it doesn't help the problem much, the request still times out before returning anything.

I'm curious as to what other options I have to achieve this.

I have considered:

- Writing a service that sits in the background and polls the
  definitions and updates the text at idle times
- Some form of caching, however this isn't really going to fix the root
  cause of the problem and beings as the site wont load at all the page
  probably wont get cached
- Implementing the regex client side, I think the page would load then
  but I doubt doing this client side would be any better than doing it
  server side it may even lock up the browser

The app is an ASP.NET website (.net 3.5 currently moving to 4 soonish), using SQL Server 2005/8 (depending on client site) and NHibernate.

Comment: It seems to me that doing the work that early is a mistake. Why not go grab the definitions server-side when the client actually requests it? When the user highlights, make an AJAX call or something to grab the definition.

Comment: I had considered that but we actually need to pre-highlight a word to indicate that there is a definition available, and for cases where words contain other words ie, "house" and "house plan" both had a definition I'm not sure how that would be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing out ideas:

- Regex would require each word to be scanned for, which would take too long.
- Compound words would require insane processing, unless it was handled in tiers.

Possible algorithm:

- Split the text into an array of strings: `text[]`
- Store the defined words in memory (just the words): `words[]`

  - Use `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet` since it has a really fast lookup
- Go through each `text[]` and tag it with a `<span class='known'>` if it is in `words[]`
- On the front end, use AJAX when the mouseover occurs

To handle compound words:

- Use regex for this.  There shouldn't be too many compound words.  If there are, then you can see which `words[]` exist before doing a regex search for the compound word.

AJAX mouseover event:

- After the tagging logic is complete, you may have span tags that are nested: `<span class='known'><span class='known'>house</span> plan</span>`, which is fine. Your jQuery will send the outermost span tag to the server and the server can return all the words that are matched.

Comment: sounds good, I'm a bit confused by what you mean in the compound words, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: After you process the text[] array, just reform the text and then do your typical regex search for the compound words.  If regex'ing compound words seems costly, you can only search for compound words that have a match. For instance, you wouldn't have to regex search 'house plans' if the document never found a match for 'house'.

Answer (score 1):

For things that take a long time to run, and don't change very often, don't forget about the lowly batch job. Parse your document into HTML pages at night. Run your regex and insert the javascript, or whatever. Then save the HTML once and serve it as many times as necessary. This is the old way, but it is still solid.